# Changing the Admin Theme in Drupal 6 Directly in Database

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'd like to restore the default admin theme in Drupal 6 via the database. Anyone know where this is stored?

Btw, there is a great answer describing how to change your site's public theme in the database  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886382/switching-themes-in-drupal-without-the-web-interface) ...I just could not get it to update my admin theme.

Answer (score 2):

List of themes you can find in {system} table, filter by type = theme, there you can set status = 1
Default theme you can find in {variable} table, filter by name = theme_default, change it to you theme name, as it is written in system table (for example, garland, not Garland). 
After this clear cache table.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps via the db:

- {system} table, filter by type=theme 
  set status=1
- {variable} table, filter by
  name=theme_default change it to you
  theme name, as it is written in
  system table
- {variable} table, filter by
  name=admin_theme change it to you
  theme name, as it is written in
  system table. Do not skip this step.
- truncate cache

Answer (score 0):

Login to your phpMyAdmin, click on SQL tab and run:

```
UPDATE system SET status=1 WHERE name = 'garland';
UPDATE variable SET value='s:7:"garland"' WHERE name = 'theme_default';
TRUNCATE cache;
```

Note that you may need to add prefix to your tables

Thanks to https://drupal.org/node/200774

Comment: For the changing the admin theme, it should be: `UPDATE variable SET value='s:7:"garland"' WHERE name = 'admin_theme';`

Answer (score 0):

If you're editing the variables in PHPMyAdmin, remember that you're editing a serialized value. This means that the value you're editing looks something like this: 's:7:"garland"'.

If you just changed "garland" to "marvin" that would change the number of letters in the serialized value from seven to six.

You'd need to change 's:**7**:"garland"' to 's:**6**:"marvin"'

That is, you'd need to count the number of letters in your new theme, and update the number following s: accordingly.