# Changing Drupal's theme and keeping Garland as the admin theme?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

How to apply a contrib theme to a Drupal-6 site without changing the administration theme -the contrib theme for the site and Garland for the administration interface- ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Administer -> Site configuration -> Administration theme. There, you can set the administration theme.  If you'd like additional control over the administration theme, use the [Admin Theme](http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module.

Answer (score 0):

For the administrator (with UID 1), go into it's user profile (in /user/edit/1) and change the theme, but set the default theme (in /admin/build/themes) to your desired theme.